# Cant't declare more than 512 floats of dynamic shared memory

Tags: cuda

I'm working with CUDA on AWS so I think the compute version is 3.0. I'm trying to declare dynamic shared memory and I checked with the debugger that it never allocates more than 512 values. Regular shared memory works

```
Kern<<<1,1,1024>>>(...)
__global__ void Kern(..) {
    __shared__ float sh[];
}
```

I used cuda-gdb and received an error accessing more than 512 elements.

Is there some sort of configuration I'm missing here? I looked through parts of the docs and didn't see any restrictions this low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third kernel configuration parameter (your value of 1024 here):

```
Kern<<<1,1,1024>>>(...) __global__ void Kern(..) { __shared__ float sh[]; }
```

is the number of *bytes* of shared memory to reserve.  A `float` quantity requires 4 bytes.  Therefore 1024 bytes is enough for 256 `float` quantities.   You are also missing the `extern` keyword from your shared variable definition, which is expected for a dynamic shared variable allocation. If you want to have 1024 `float` quantities available per threadblock, you will need a value of 4096 instead of 1024, like this:

```
Kern<<<1,1,4096>>>(...) __global__ void Kern(..) { extern __shared__ float sh[]; }
```

You may also want to read about [shared memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared) in the programming guide.